# How to use loop to create multiple columns

Tags: r

I am struggling with creating multiple columns in a DRY way.
I have searched google and stack exchange and I am still struggling with the below.

```
df <- data.frame(red = 1:10, blue=seq(1,30,3))

myfunction <- function(x){
  log(x) + 10
}

df$green <- myfunction(df$red)
df$yellow <- myfunction(df$blue)
```

My questions are:
how can I create the green and yellow columns using a for loop?
how can I create the green and yellow using an apply function?

Comment: `lapply` would be standard practice for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Sotos, apply is slower than lapply. So I believe the optimal solution is:

```
df[,c("green","yellow")] <- lapply(df, myfunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a bit of time working on these kinds of things. Most of the time you're going to want to either know all the names of the new variables or have them work in an orderly pattern so you can just paste together the names with an indexing variable.

```
df <- data.frame(red = 1:10, blue=seq(1,30,3))

myfunction <- function(x){
  log(x) + 10
}

newcols = apply(X = df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = myfunction)
colnames(newcols) = c("greeen","yellow")
df = cbind(df,newcols)

# Alternative
df <- data.frame(red = 1:10, blue=seq(1,30,3))
colors = c("green", "yellow")
for(i in 1:length(colors)){
  df[,colors[i]] = myfunction(df[,i])
}
```

Comment: It's better not to use `apply` on data.frames. The usual operations are `sapply` or `lapply`

Comment: I use all of those frequently. Why do you mention this @Sotos

Comment: Because `apply` will coerce to matrix

Comment: Okay... at the end of the script `df` is a data frame as intended!

Comment: Yes, I know. Have a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/5635580) It will clarify it

Comment: <3 that post and have used it many times. I still don't get it but have fun!

Comment: It is not efficient to be coersing to matrix before doing operations. That is why `apply` is not advised for data frames.

Comment: My life is inefficient

Comment: I have no say in that. I m talking about R